# How can i count the detected objects on image?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Now I'm making a program to detect and count objects in an image. My code based on [this code](https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10).

There is no problem detecting objects in the image, but it cannot find a way to count them.

someone said, add the

```
print([category_index.get(i) for i in classes[0]])
print(scores)
```

on `object_detection_image.py`

but, nothing happened.

```
def visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
    image,
    boxes,
    classes,
    scores,
    category_index,
    instance_masks=None,
    instance_boundaries=None,
    keypoints=None,
    use_normalized_coordinates=False,
    max_boxes_to_draw=20,
    min_score_thresh=.5,
    agnostic_mode=False,
    line_thickness=4,
    groundtruth_box_visualization_color='black',
    skip_scores=False,
    skip_labels=False,
    class_name(print(class_name)):
```

Answer (score 0):

you can find it by .shape property of boxes and after that find the length of that shape

```
 print(len(boxes.shape))
```

to get the number of boxes

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm sorry. but Can you tell me where to put it?

Comment: at last of your code

Comment: Thanks. but i added it end of visualization_utils.py and object_detection_image.py but it didn't work.. What did I do wrong?

Comment: if you have any problem regarding this then you can refer to this link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45543154/how-to-count-objects-in-tensorflow-object-detection-api

Comment: Thank you very much. We've solved the problem with your help. Thank you very much!!!!

Comment: I'm glad to hear that. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @J.J if this solution work for you then please accept it as answer so that others would prefer it.