# How can I get every different detected object as in a list?

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

By using Tensorflow pre-trained COCO model, I'm trying to get every detected object from a frame and trying to store them that every sinle one of them will have a different label.

For example:

```
ist=[["person1_info"],["person2_info']]
```

I search some of stack overflow page like that one, [How to count objects in Tensorflow Object Detection API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45543154/how-to-count-objects-in-tensorflow-object-detection-api) but I could not have a clear result. Main loop is in the below:

```
  boxes = np.squeeze(boxes)
  scores = np.squeeze(scores)
  classes = np.squeeze(classes)

  indices = np.argwhere(classes == 1)
  boxes = np.squeeze(boxes[indices])

  scores = np.squeeze(scores[indices])
  classes = np.squeeze(classes[indices])

  # Visualization of the results of a detection.
  vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
      image_np,
      np.squeeze(boxes),
      np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
      np.squeeze(scores),
      category_index,
      use_normalized_coordinates=True,
      line_thickness=8)

  cv2.imshow('object detection', cv2.resize(image_np, (800,600)))

  if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    break
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more about what you are trying to do? Do you want to have list like this: `ist=[[x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max, label, score],...]`?

Comment: Yes, I could say that I want a coordinate list that is similar to as you mentioned. But it should be for every person in a frame. If there are three detected person in a frame, list should include these detected boxes coordinate for every single one. I search a little bit and 'visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array()' include a parameter 'track_ids' but could not figure out.

Answer (score 0):

To create custom output list you can do it like this:

```
(im_width, im_height, _) = frame.shape
boxes = np.squeeze(boxes)
scores = np.squeeze(scores)
classes = np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32)
out = []
for box, score, obj_class in zip(boxes, scores, classes):
    xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = box

    # delete this if you need to keep normalized coordinates
    (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax) = (xmin * im_width, xmax * im_width,
                                ymin * im_height, ymax * im_height)
    out.append([xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, obj_class, score])
```

Comment: I guess I was not clear while trying to tell my problem. Actually these code blocks are what I wanted implicitly. What I want exactly is to distinguish every person in a frame. For example if there is a man in frame the boxed obj class should be 1 and second people should be 2 so on. They all should be uniqe. I hope it is clear. However these codes also helped me.

Comment: You need tracker for this task, TensorFlow Object Detection API doesn't have tracker included. You can use trackers from other sources to assign id for every person. There are some trackers implemented in OpenCV or, for example, you can use SORT tracker: https://github.com/abewley/sort

Comment: This is what I am looking for. Right now I have a clear vision what is going on with trackers. After little searching I also found other tracker types. I really appreaciate your help, otherwise I would stick to this problem.