# Raspberry pi - Tensorflow How to detect in real time only people and counting?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, tensorflow, raspberry-pi

I try to make a camera with a raspberry pi that counts and sends on firebase the number of person exat in the pieces.

I followed the tutorial of https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-on-the-Raspberry-Pi
but I can not limit detection only to the person and count the number of people to detect in the room. I can send to firebase but I do not have the right number of people.

i tried several answers on stackeoverflow but its not working as [How to count objects in Tensorflow Object Detection API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45543154/how-to-count-objects-in-tensorflow-object-detection-api)
because they do not have the problem of just counting people.

How can I count only people in a room ?
Here is my code :

```
    for frame1 in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr",use_video_port=True):
    totalcount=0
    t1 = cv2.getTickCount()

    # Acquire frame and expand frame dimensions to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
    # i.e. a single-column array, where each item in the column has the pixel RGB value
    frame = np.copy(frame1.array)
    frame.setflags(write=1)
    frame_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    frame_expanded = np.expand_dims(frame_rgb, axis=0)

    # Perform the actual detection by running the model with the image as input
    (boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run(
        [detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections],
        feed_dict={image_tensor: frame_expanded})
    boxes = np.squeeze(boxes)
    scores = np.squeeze(scores)
    classes = np.squeeze(classes)


    indices = np.argwhere(classes == 1)
    boxes = np.squeeze(boxes[indices])
    scores = np.squeeze(scores[indices])
    classes = np.squeeze(classes[indices])



    # Draw the results of the detection (aka 'visulaize the results')
    vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
        frame,
        boxes,
        classes,
        scores,
        category_index,
        use_normalized_coordinates=True,
        line_thickness=8,
        min_score_thresh=0.70)

    cv2.putText(frame,"FPS: {0:.2f}".format(frame_rate_calc),(30,50),font,1,(255,255,0),2,cv2.LINE_AA)
    #print(category_index)

    try:
        app = firebase_admin.get_app()
    except ValueError as e:
        cred = credentials.Certificate("./ServiceAccountKey.json")
        app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

    store = firestore.client()
    #doc_ref = store.collection(u'users').limit(2)

    print(len(boxes.shape))

    totalcount= boxes.shape[1]

    #x = re.search('[\w]', str(totalcount))

    #totalcount = x.group()
    print("Il y'a {0} personne dans la salle".format(totalcount))            
    # All the results have been drawn on the frame, so it's time to display it.
    store.collection(u'Piece').document(u'Cuisine').set({u'nbrPers': int(totalcount)})

    cv2.putText(frame,"NbrPerson"+str(totalcount) ,(50, 45),font,0.8,(0, 0xFF, 0xFF),2,cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,)

    cv2.imshow('Object detector', frame)

    t2 = cv2.getTickCount()
    time1 = (t2-t1)/freq
    frame_rate_calc = 1/time1

    # Press 'q' to quit
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break

    rawCapture.truncate(0)

camera.close()
```